# clearing the content of the html editor

Tags: php, jquery

i do have text-box and two check boxes which i am able to clear its values on button click:

```
$("#cleartext").live('click', function () {
        $(this).parents('form').find('input[type="text"]').val('');
        $(".check").attr("checked", false);
    });
```

but i do have a textarea in which i am using the html editor but i am not able to clear 
the value of it so please suggest me on this
the view of this elements are as follows:

```
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" required title="required" placeholder="title" data-bind="value:title" />
                            <input type="checkbox" id="active" name="active" class="check" data-bind="checked: active=='true'"  />Active
                            <input type="checkbox" id="logon" name="logon" class="check" data-bind="checked: use_logo=='true'"  />Logo
    <textarea id="iiii" name="iiii" class="htmleditor" rows="9" cols="50" style="width: 600px; height: 190px;"></textarea>
<button type="button" class="btn"  id="cleartext">New Contract</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried $('#iiii').val(''); ?

Comment: What do you mean under `html editor`? Is that some WYSIWYG editor or simple textarea?

Comment: @DevangRathod textarea does not have value attribute.

Comment: Which textarea are you using?

Comment: I'm right what? :) WYSIWYG plugin or simple textarea?

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar i did mistake i know so i remove.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ENGKa/ - here val works fine. But maybe you have an older jQuery version?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Yeah, there is no value for textarea, but jQuery can handle that.

Comment: @Devang is there any input type textarea u knw??

Comment: And how it is called? There are many of such plugins. And each one has own API.

Comment: var wysihtml5Editor222 = $('#iiii').wysihtml5().data("wysihtml5").editor;
@ FAngel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I found correct plugin, below should work fine:

```
$('#iiii').data("wysihtml5").editor.clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

Which HTML editor you are using..

FCK or similar open source editors have respective methods to clear all contents

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function resetEditor(id) {
FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance(id).SetData('');
}
</script>.
```

For wysihtml5 try below

```
var rte = $('#description').wysihtml5();
   rte.setValue('');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion and Correction**

The function `$.live()` is deprecated. So change the following code:

```
$("body").on('click', "#cleartext", function () {
    $(this).parents('form').find('input[type="text"]').val('');
    $(".check").attr("checked", false);
});
```

Now depending on the textarea, say for eg. Redactor, you need to clear this way:

```
editor.setCode('<p></p>');
```

Comment: a simple textarea can be cleared bt here i am using wysihtml5Editor

Answer (score 0):

As said by Praveen Kumar, `$.live()` is deprecated. The following should work, and clear the textarea:

```
$("body").on("click", "#cleartext", function() {
    $(this).parents("#your-form").find("input[type='text']").val("");
    $(".check").attr("checked", false);
    $("#iiii").val("");
});
```

But if your function is being called frequently, you should bind `$.on()` on a closer block. You should also avoid `$.parents()`, because those functions are heavy.

Comment: a simple textarea can be cleared bt here i am using wysihtml5Editor